# showing json array with array location

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Hello I am new to Android. My problem is with my `json` value:

```js
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM textviewtable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    $json = json_encode($row);
  }
}
else {
 echo "0 results";
}

echo $json;

$conn->close();
?>
```

**JSON**

> [
>    {"id":"8","ServerData":"ABC","name":"xyz","pincode":"123456"},
>    {"id":"9","ServerData":"DEF","name":"JHG","pincode":"654321"},
>    {"id":"10","ServerData":"GHI","name":"KIH","pincode":"142536"}
>   ]

The Json `ServerData`, `name` and `pincode` objects are the same on each row but I need each row's  `ServerData`, `name` and `pincode` to be different.

So, for the first row I want to show `ServerData`,`name`, `pincode` and for the second row I want to show `ServerData1`, `name1`, `pincode1` etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's only showing one row is because in each loop you're just redefining the `$json` variable. You need to store each row in an array and the echo that.

Try changing your code to:

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM textviewtable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $data = [];

    //output data of each row

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Hope this helps!